# Set of vectors in c++

Tags: c++, vector, set

How I can get the elements in the vectors set? This is the code I have :

```
std::set< std::vector<int> > conjunto;
std::vector<int> v0 = std::vector<int>(3);
v0[0]=0;
v0[1]=10;
v0[2]=20;
std::cout << v0[0];
conjunto.insert(v0);
v0[0]=1;
v0[1]=11;
v0[2]=22;
conjunto.insert(v0);
std::set< std::vector<int> >::iterator it; 
std::cout << conjunto.size();
for( it = conjunto.begin(); it != conjunto.end(); it++)
   std::cout << *it[0] ;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close. You need to pull the vector out of the set iterator. See below.

```
main()
{
  std::set< std::vector<int> > conjunto;
  std::vector<int> v0 = std::vector<int>(3);
  v0[0]=0;
  v0[1]=10;
  v0[2]=20;
  std::cout << v0[0] << endl;
  conjunto.insert(v0);
  v0[0]=1;
  v0[1]=11;
  v0[2]=22;
  conjunto.insert(v0);
  std::set< std::vector<int> >::iterator it;
  std::cout << "size = " << conjunto.size() << endl;
  for( it = conjunto.begin(); it != conjunto.end(); it++) {
    const std::vector<int>& i = (*it); // HERE we get the vector
    std::cout << i[0] << endl;  // NOW we output the first item.
  }
```

**Output:**

```
$ ./a.out 
0
size = 2
0
1
```

Answer (score 9):

The `[]` operator takes precedence over the `*` operator, so you want to change the `for` loop to:

```
for (it = conjunto.begin(); it != conjunto.end(); it++)
    std::cout << (*it)[0] << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

Now, with C++11 standart, it's easier:

```
set< vector<int> > conjunto;
// filling conjunto ...
for (vector<int>& v: conjunto)
    cout << v[0] << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
std::set<std::vector<int> >::const_iterator it = cunjunto.begin();
std::set<std::vector<int> >::const_iterator itEnd = conjunto.end();

for(; it != itEnd; ++it)
{
   // Here *it references the element in the set (vector)
   // Therefore, declare iterators to loop the vector and print it's elements.
   std::vector<int>::const_iterator it2 = (*it).begin();
   std::vector<int>::const_iterator it2End = (*it).end();

   for (; it2 != it2End; ++it2)
     std::cout << *it2;
}
```